# "Deus meus", aut "Deus mī"?

Tags: morphology, declension, vulgata, vocative

I was taught that *meus* had a special irregular vocative, *mī*. (So "my father" in the vocative would be *pater mī*, not *pater meus*.)

However, there's a line that shows up a few times in the Vulgate that seems to contradict this.

> *Deus, Deus **meus**, respice in me: quare me dereliquisti?*
> God, my God, look back to me: why have you forsaken me? (Psalms 21:2 or 22:2 depending on version)
>
> *Et circa horam nonam clamavit Jesus voce magna, dicens: Eli, Eli, lamma sabacthani? hoc est: Deus **meus**, Deus **meus**, ut quid dereliquisti me?*
> And around the ninth hour Jesus cried out in a loud voice, saying, *Eli, Eli, lamma sabacthani*? That is: my God, my God, why have you forsaken me? (Matthew 27:46)
>
> *Et hora nona exclamavit Jesus voce magna, dicens: Eloi, eloi, lamma sabacthani? quod est interpretatum: Deus **meus**, Deus **meus**, ut quid dereliquisti me?*
> And at the ninth hour Jesus exclaimed in a loud voice, saying, *Eloi, eloi, lamma sabacthani*? Which is translated: my God, my God, why have you forsaken me? (Mark 15:34)

The conjugation of the verb makes it clear that the speaker is addressing God directly. So why do all these instances use *meus* instead of *mī*?

Comment: Related https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/8856/39

Comment: Stotz 1998 (v.4, §24.1-24.2) explains it very clearly: "Zu dem Poss'pron. *meus* lautet die Voc.-Form *mi*, doch wird hier seit alters (Plautus) auch *meus* gebraucht, und zwar nicht nur in Verbindung mit einer subst. Anrede auf -*us* (vgl. oben *deus meus*), sondern auch in Formeln wie *domine meus* (vgl. *popule meus*, § 24.1). Mitunter mögen rhythmische bzw. metrische Gründe einwirken. So verwender Hrotsvit meist *mi*, läßt jedoch einen Hexameter beginnen mit: *accipe, care meus*."

Comment: @AlexB. That would make a good answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the empirical facts, which are pretty much beyond controversy.

1. In classical Latin, there is no (textually secure*) attested vocative form of *deus*. That is, *dee* does not exist, and *deus* is not used as a vocative.
2. When a vocative *deus* became necessary for Christian Latin, they employed the nominative form *deus* rather than creating a new vocative form.
3. This was considered a nominative used in place of a vocative, not as a vocative form. Thus, the adjective *meus* was used for agreement. We can see this by the occurrence of phrases such as *Domine, deus meus*. We do not see *deus* regarded as a true vocative form, and thus used in phrases such as *mi Deus*, until well into the Middle Ages.

Now, some additional information, which is more controversial among scholars.

1. The original choice to use the nominative *deus* instead of inventing a vocative may have been based on the nominative for vocative construction found in the Greek Septuagint and New Testament (Wackernagel, *Lectures on Syntax*, 18-19 et passim.)
2. Some level of opposition to vocatives ending in -*ee* and to the vocative *mi* are visible within classical Latin literature, and these factors may sufficiently explain the choice of *deus meus* even apart from Greek influence. See [Dickey](https://www.academia.edu/8113205/O_dee_ree_pie_The_Vocative_Problems_of_Latin_Words_Ending_in_-eus_in_Glotta_2002_), "O Dee Ree Pie: The Vocative of Latin Words Ending in -*eus*".

*John Rauk, "The Classical Vocative of *Deus* and Its Problems," adduces two instances of *deus* used vocatively. But both passages are suspected of textual corruption, and one of them cannot even be distinguished from a nominative-for-vocative.

Comment: "which are pretty much beyond controversy" - "In classical Latin, there is no attested vocative form of deus. That is, dee does not exist" - I wouldn't put it that strongly. See, for example, Rauk, John. "The Vocative of Deus and Its Problems." Classical Philology 92, no. 2 (1997): 138-49.

Comment: There is no textually secure attestation. Both his examples, as he himself goes on to say, exist in passages of dubious authenticity. Given how common a word "deus" is, it's practically impossible that a vocative form existed of which we have no attestation.

Comment: "In the end it is necessary to recognize that for all the armament of scholarship that can be brought to bear upon it, **the vocative of deus is a question that must be left open**. All that we can do is say what the vocative of deus might have been. We cannot say what it was"  [emphasis mine - Alex B.].

Comment: "Given how common a word "deus" is, it's practically impossible that a vocative form existed of which we have no attestation" - that is a fallacious argument. Just because a word is frequently used (in some case form) does not mean its vocative form must be frequent too.

Comment: That's not a contradiction of what I said. I said there is no attested vocative form, which is true if you don't include the dubious text from Scribonius. The passage in the Carmina doesn't have an adjective, so there's no way to distinguish whether it's a true vocative or nominative for vocative. Rauk is saying that in the absence of attestation, it should be an open question. I said that there is an absence of attestation.

Comment: Dickey goes into the rest of this. You should read her. We have plenty of attestations of dea as a vocative, and male gods are addressed more often than female gods. Therefore, we should expect more vocative forms of deus than dea, but we have none. This same pattern holds for adjectives ending in -eus, so it seems clear that there's a conscious choice to avoid such words.

Comment: Which paper by Dickey do you refer to, Dickey 2000? She does say that the masculine singular vocative of deus is avoided for phonological and stylistic reasons (Dickey 2002). I've read her book, among many other things written by her - she's one of my favorite scholars, actually. :)

Comment: Just wanted to make it clear. It's not that I disagree with you - quite the opposite, actually. I was responding to the "beyond controversy" part, that's all.

Comment: Thanks. I'll edit my answer to put in a caveat. Yes, my reading of Dickey 2000 (and she repeats this in her 2002 book) is that the Latin authors avoided the singular vocative of deus to the point that we can't know whether one even existed.

Comment: Perhaps your no. 3 explains the nominative of [_agnus Dei_](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4904/why-not-agne-dei/4906#4906) in _Gloria in excelsis_, if the three titles are considered together: _Domine Deus, agnus Dei, Filius Patris_

Comment: @Rafael I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but I can see a connection. Sometimes, after an initial vocative, nouns in apposition take the nominative. If Deus was regarded as a nominative, perhaps there was a desire to keep using nominatives from that point on. Certainly we need some reason why the same texts uses both fili and filius.